# Is there any way to modify JSTree to partially block HTML execution instead of simply setting "force_text" to true?

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I'm trying to modify/use the jstree library to allow a mixed HTML execution settings. Normally, blocking HTML can be achieved by setting force_text to true.

Renaming the node to `<b>New Node</b>` would cause the text to be rendered as plain text `<b>New Node</b>` when force_text is set to true and to **Node Name** when force_Text is set to false.

The problem arose, when it was discovered that force_text = false can cause errors and is not exactly safe/valid for customer use. For example renaming node to `<New_Node>` causes the node name to go blank and changes the name inside of node data attibutes to HTML markup `<new node=""></new>`.

I'd have used the force_text option to deal with this, yet I need a different behavior from the nodes. Right now a prefix for the node name can be set with a different input box(It is sent to database before it's showed in the tree, so no problem with HTML rendering here). It is added to the node name when renaming is completed or node is loaded. To make it look good, parentheses and  is added to it in the code, so the end result looks like:

**(Prefix)** Node_Name

However setting force_text to true makes achieving this impossible. The text defaults(as expected) to:

`<b>(Prefix)</b> Node_Name`

Apart from trying to send a text to jstree through rename_node and set_text methods, which yielded no results, as the library just turns HTML into plain text.
Then I delved into the library itself to look for a way to modify it to suit my needs(I know, it's not advised, not the best option, but checked everything else outside of that. At least everything that I know of). The method "redraw_node", which uses text attribute of the node to show text, looked promising to modify, and even gave good results(I am aware of other places in which I would need to take those changes into account). I changed the part of the code, which sets node text from:

```
if(this.settings.core.force_text) {
node.childNodes[1].appendChild(d.createTextNode(obj.text));
}
else {
node.childNodes[1].innerHTML += obj.text;
}
```

To:

```
if (this.settings.core.force_text) {
    node.childNodes[1].appendChild(d.createTextNode(obj.text));
}
else {
    if (obj.type === "node_with_prefix_type") {
        if (obj.text !== "" || obj.text !== undefined) {
            node.childNodes[1].innerHTML += obj.text;
        }
        else {
            node.childNodes[1].innerHTML += obj.data.prefix === undefined || obj.data.prefix === "" ? "" : obj.data.prefix;
            node.childNodes[1].appendChild(d.createTextNode(obj.data.name));
        }
    }
    else {
        node.childNodes[1].innerHTML += obj.text;
    }
}
```

The code above tried serializing the node text(of a certain type only - prototype code, sorry) from its data attribute. It worked okay for the most part, but copy-paste events proved to be problematic. When first sent to redraw_node data attribute during copy-paste operation, the data value is undefined but is copied later, and I have no access to original node data.

So the question is - is there any way to achieve this boldened prefix with safe HTML-free node name text without modifying the library? Completely disallowing the usage of HTML markups and deleting them inside of the name using regex or even deleting angle brackets? If impossible, how would you go about doing this?